# JPA2 Criteria API creates invalid SQL when using groupBy

Tags: postgresql, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

JPA2 with the Criteria API seems to generate invalid SQL for PostgreSQL. For this code:

```java
Root<DBObjectAccessCounter> from = query.from(DBObjectAccessCounter.class);
Path<DBObject> object = from.get(DBObjectAccessCounter_.object);
Expression<Long> sum = builder.sumAsLong(from.get(DBObjectAccessCounter_.count));
query.multiselect(object, sum).groupBy(object);
```

I get the following exception:

```
ERROR: column "dbobject1_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY
clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

The generated SQL is:

```sql
select dbobjectac0_.object_id as col_0_0_,
    sum(dbobjectac0_.count) as col_1_0_, dbobject1_.id as id1001_,
    dbobject1_.name as name1013_,
    dbobject1_.lastChanged as lastChan2_1013_,
    dbobject1_.type_id as type3_1013_
    from DBObjectAccessCounter dbobjectac0_
    inner join DBObject dbobject1_
    on dbobjectac0_.object_id=dbobject1_.id
    group by dbobjectac0_.object_id
```

Obviously, the first item of the select statement (dbobjectac0_.object_id) does not match the group by clause.

## Simplified example

It does not even work for this simple example:

```java
Root<DBObjectAccessCounter> from = query.from(DBObjectAccessCounter.class);
Path<DBObject> object = from.get(DBObjectAccessCounter_.object);
query.select(object).groupBy(object);
```

which returns

```sql
select dbobject1_.id as id924_, dbobject1_.name as name933_,
    dbobject1_.lastChanged as lastChan2_933_,
    dbobject1_.type_id as type3_933_
    from DBObjectAccessCounter dbobjectac0_
    inner join DBObject dbobject1_
    on dbobjectac0_.object_id=dbobject1_.id
    group by dbobjectac0_.object_id
```

and produces the same error as above.

## Grouping by ID Instead of Type

Grouping by the ID as suggested by the error message with

```java
Root<DBObjectAccessCounter> from = query.from(DBObjectAccessCounter.class);
Path<DBObject> object = from.get(DBObjectAccessCounter_.object);
Path<Long> objectId = from.get(DBObjectAccessCounter_.object).get(DBObject_.id);
query.select(object).groupBy(objectId);
```

also results in the same error.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `object.id` in your `groupBy` clause? Does `groupBy(object)` implicitly mean "group by the primary key" in JPA? Or "group by all fields"? Can you show the error produced by the simplified example?

Comment: I added an example with grouping by object id which results in the same error. This error message appears at all mentioned example.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL 9.2 and above has an improvement in how it detects "implicitly grouped" columns, ie where you've put the primary key in `group by` so all fields from that table may be referenced in the SELECT list. Prior versions didn't detect this so `SELECT id, somefield FROM sometable GROUP BY id` would result in `Column sometable.somefield must appear in the GROUP BY clause`. In newer versions Pg will detect that `somefield` is implicitly grouped because the `id` is included and permit this query to run.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure that'll solve your problem; your problem is that you're grouping by the key on the other side of the join condition, where I doubt Pg will recognise it as a PK since that column isn't marked as such.

I suggest you write a self-contained test case and file an issue report on the Hibernate JIRA. Link to it here; once there's a complete and runnable test case I'll have a play and see.

Also, are you sure the error message remains *exactly* the same in your changed test case, it doesn't refer to a differently-numbered alias or anything?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I created the JIRA with the required test case: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/JPA-34

Comment: @Stephan I don't know if you can change it now you've filed it, but it should really be filed under `HIBERNATE` not `JPA`. The `JPA` project is for the specification.

Comment: @Stephan I've re-filed it as https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7611; might want to add yourself as a watcher.

Comment: @Stephan When you watch it, vote on it too. BTW, converted the test case to EclipseLink and the simpler two tests pass but the testGroupByWithSum fails there too. I'm not convinced `testGroupByWithSum` is correct. Can you DL the EclipseLink-converted test and play with that, see if you can get `testGroupByWithSum` to work?

Comment: I moved the bugreport to HHH. Should your new one specified as a duplicate?

Comment: @Stephan Wasn't sure if you could do that, so I refiled. Apparently I can't close or delete my own JIRA issue (grr!) but I've flagged it as a dup. Sorry, I forget how little that JIRA lets you do.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your first example on `EclipseLink` and `MySql`. It doesn't throw any exception and, if I haven't misunderstood your goal, the resulting query is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.name, SUM(t1.count) 
FROM dbobject t0, dbobjectaccesscounter t1 
WHERE (t0.id = t1.object_id) GROUP BY t0.id, t0.name
```